# Is there a shorter/more efficient way to use the spread operator in javascript to update a key's value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I recently got interested on using the spread operator syntax, so I tried some examples, I have this example of array:

```
var entities = [
  {
    "id": 1,    
    "age": 33,
    "hobby": "games"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "age": 28,
    "hobby": "chess"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "age": 21,
    "hobby": "comics"
  },
  {
    "age": 23,
    "hobby": "games"
  }
]
```

Then, to update all hobbies at "once" I do the following:

```
entities.forEach(function(entity, index) {
  this[index] = {...entity, hobby: "Some String to update all hobbies"};
}, entities);
console.log(entities)
```

Which works but I was wondering if there's a more efficient or shorter way to achieve it while using the spread operator. Any suggestions?
EDIT:
forEach is not necessary for me, or even do it in that way, I was curious on whether the spread syntax could be used (or not) to update nested values

Comment: why not just update the property `entities.forEach(function(entity) {
  entity.hobby = "Some String to update all hobbies";
});`?

Comment: Well, you're already looping over entities.  Why do you need the spread at all?  `entity.hobby = 'new value'` works, no?

Comment: I know @Taplar, please check my edit, I know I can do that as you and Nina suggested (or even with map) just got curious about this particular case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spread operator doesn't really help when you're updating the list, like you do in your example. It's easier to just update the property of each object:

```js
var entities = [ { "id": 1, "age": 33, "hobby": "games" }, { "id": 2, "age": 28, "hobby": "chess" }, { "id": 3, "age": 21, "hobby": "comics" }, { "age": 23, "hobby": "games" } ]

entities.forEach(entity => {
  entity.hobby = "Some String to update all hobbies";
});

console.log(entities)
```

The spread operator is useful if you want to create copies of objects, like you might want to do in a `.map`:

```js
var entities = [ { "id": 1, "age": 33, "hobby": "games" }, { "id": 2, "age": 28, "hobby": "chess" }, { "id": 3, "age": 21, "hobby": "comics" }, { "age": 23, "hobby": "games" } ]

const newEntities = entities.map(entity =>
  ({...entity, hobby: "Some String to update all hobbies"})
);

console.log(newEntities)
```

Comment: "The spread operator is useful if you want to create copies of objects" You might want to note that this only makes a shallow copy. If any of the values in `entity` are themselves objects, the new object created with the spread operator will still have references to those object values.

Comment: you beat me to it!!

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator will iterate over all keys in the object to copy them and their values into the new object. If you want more efficiency, don't use the spread operator. Just assign directly to each object as you iterate over the list:

```
entity.hobby = "Some String to update all hobbies"
```

Note that this modifies the object in the existing array. So you don't need to assign `this[index]`. Alternatively, you can use `map()` instead of `foreach()` to return a new array that is created from the existing array.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is really needed for what you are doing?

You can also look into [this link](https://medium.com/@photokandy/es2015-array-from-rest-and-spread-449651a1851f) for some interesting usage of the spread, Array.from and rest operator.

More into just spread operator [here](https://davidwalsh.name/spread-operator).

If you are looking for a fancier/smaller way to write this, here's two, one that uses uses .map and spread to return a copy of entities, and another that uses .forEach and updates the same array entities:

```js
 const COMMON_HOBBY = 'Coding';
 let entities = [{
        "id": 1,    
        "age": 33,
        "hobby": "games"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "age": 28,
        "hobby": "chess"
      }];


    // To assign to new array (copy)
    let output = entities.map((entity) => ({...entity, hobby: COMMON_HOBBY }));
    console.log(output);

    // Mutate /edit same array entities 
    entities.forEach((entity) => entity.hobby = COMMON_HOBBY );
    console.log(entities);
```